# Python in HTML page without installing extra software/libraries

Tags: python, html

Is there a way to use python on a HTML page without any extra libraries/software? I am on a school computer and they will not let me add anything. The program accesses some data from another site,does some calculations and outputs the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "use python on a HTML page"?  At the very least you'd need a web server and Python installed.

Comment: Are you looking for an online Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think I completely misunderstood the question.

If you *have* Python and want to run a web server on your computer without any additional software, my answer below stands.

If you *don't* have Python, you can use an in-your-browser Python like [ReplIt](https://repl.it/languages/python3) or [CodeAcademy](http://labs.codecademy.com/).

---

While it is *possible* to run "python in a web page", it is much more usual to have "python which generates a web page" or "python which renders a web page template".

A quick example (Python 2.x) of a [simple Python web server](http://www.acmesystems.it/python_httpd) (all libraries involved are part of Python, not add-ons).

Then, on the line `self.wfile.write("Hello World !")` you can replace `"Hello World !"` with `<html><body>This is a web page!</body></html>`.

Obviously if your html gets complicated this can be a bit messy, so you can instead have a template file like

```
<html><body>
{message}
</body></html>
```

and render it like

```
with open("mytemplate.html") as inf:
    template = inf.read()
result = template.format(message="This is a web page !")
self.wfile.write(result)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score -2):

Skulpt allows python to be run in a webpage- here is a link
http://www.skulpt.org/

Comment: Didn't you want to avoid any *extra libraries/software*?

Comment: you don't need extra libraries/software. This runs off notepad and you just copy and paste the html code and then you can add the python code yourself.